# Installing PyGMO on Mac OS X Yosemite - missing boost-python3?

Tags: python, boost, python-3.4, boost-python

I've been trying to install `PyGMO` on my Mac OS X 10.10. I'm using `Anaconda Python 2.3`, so it comes with `python 3.4`.

I followed the instructions on http://esa.github.io/pygmo/install.html and did try to build `boost` manually but didn't have much luck with building `boost-python`... The instructions I could find on the official website was very limited...

While using ccmake to run the build file in pagmo/build directory, it complained that it did not find `boost-python3`...

So I reverted to using `brew` to install `boost`. Thanks to the info I found on this page: http://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/Mac-OSX-Build-Boost-Python-with-Python3-Support/

Now I have both boost and boost-python installed, but still the `ccmake` process for `PyGMO` complains about not being able to find `boost-python3`.

Are there any environment variables I need to set? In the `ccmake` config screen do I need to set `Boost_PYTHON3_LIBRARY_RELEASE` or `Boost_PYTHON3_LIBRARY_DEBUG`?

**LATEST EDIT: This SHA256 below mis-match is resolved. Turned out it was caused by source forge site being down when I ran the commands... Some better error messages would have helped.**

*However, when I tried to get boost and boost-python with `brew`, I got the following `SHA256` hash code mismatch error.*

*Anyone has any idea how to fix this?*

```
>$ sudo brew install boost-python --with-python3
==> Installing boost-python dependency: boost
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/b...
####################################################################### 100.0%
==> Pouring boost-1.58.0.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
 /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.58.0: 10718 files, 486M
==> Installing boost-python
==> Downloading https://downloads.sourceforge....
==> Downloading from http://downloads.sourceforge.n...
####################################################################### 100.0%
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: fdfc204fc33ec79c99b9a74944c3e54bd78be4f7f15e260c0e2700a36dc7d3e5
Actual: 818a4b8bbcb50878a8b1b9f71b4274d242ab46bf860c74676e98dec1d0248821
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/boost-python-1.58.0.tar.bz2
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.
```

*Tried to delete the cached `boost` package files as suggested a few times but it didn't work either.*

Thanks guys.

Comment: Just noticed that sourceforge.net is down.. Maybe that's why. Will try again tomorrow and update.

Comment: this was sourceforge.net's issue.. now the brew installation works fine. but problem still persists, see edits in post above. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok problem resolved. Here's the best practice to get boost on Mac OS X.

Use Homebrew! but the key is to use the `--with-python3` switch! Credits to this page: http://ryanclouser.com/2015/07/16/Mac-OSX-Build-Boost-Python-with-Python3-Support/

```
>$ brew install boost-python --with-python3
```

Assuming you have `CMake` already, just follow the instructions on PyGMO's website.

```
pagmo/build>$ ccmake ../
```

This will then bring up the config screen, everything should look fine. If not, do `rm -rf *` in `pagmo/build` folder to clear everything and start again (this resolved the issue with `boost-python3` for me mentioned above.

Then run `make` and `sudo make install` as mentioned on the website.

`PyGMO` should be ready for use in python after that!

I had the following error message. However, if I start `python` in the `~/anaconda/lib` folder where I have my `anaconda` installed, `import PyGMO` worked, so it's probably some library path thing that needs to be fixed.

```
>>> import PyGMO as gmo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyGMO/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from PyGMO import core, algorithm, migration, problem, topology, test, util
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyGMO/core/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyGMO.core._core import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyGMO/core/_core.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: libpython3.4m.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyGMO/core/_core.so
  Reason: image not found
```

**Latested EDIT: ** Did some searching around, a partial solution to the import error above, is to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/anaconda/lib`. With this, imports will work when you launch `python` in a console. However, `IPython-notebook` would not start for me... Also have seen that Max OS doesn't really have a dynamic search also...